# How to properly make my own module that imports another module within it?

Tags: python, class, csv, module, python-2.7

I use a .txt file with this, and each line looks like the following:

```
 1/2/09,902,898.5,905.25,913.25,914.5,914.25,915.5,924.5,926.25,929.25,927.5,926
```

There are probably 50 such lines in the .txt file.

Here is the code that I made:

```
class PriceProcesseor(object):

    import csv
    import datetime

    def __init__(self, text_file_with_prices):
        self.text_file_with_prices = text_file_with_prices
        self.file_each_date_is_a_list_of_strings = self.__turn_file_into_list()

    def __turn_file_into_list(self):
        self.text_file_with_prices1 = open(self.text_file_with_prices, 'rU')
        self.text_file_with_prices2 = csv.reader(self.text_file_with_prices1)
        return self.text_file_with_prices2

    def file_as_list(self):
        '''Returns the file as a list of strings'''
        self.whole_file_as_list_of_lists = []
        for x in self.file_each_date_is_a_list_of_strings:
            self.whole_file_as_list_of_lists.append(x)
        return self.whole_file_as_list_of_lists

    # Make a method that can return any given line

    def return_line(self,line_number):
        self.line_number = line_number
        return self.file_as_list()[line_number]

    def the_works(self):
        self.the_works_list = []
        for date in self.file_as_list():
            self.mini_list = []
            for item in date:
                if '/' in item:
                    self.date = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%m/%d/%y'))
                    self.date_munged = self.date.strip('00:00:00')
                    self.date_munged_1 = self.date_munged.strip()
                    self.mini_list.append(self.date_munged_1)
                elif '/' not in item:
                    self.mini_list.append(float(item))
            self.the_works_list.append(self.mini_list)
        return self.the_works_list
```

But when I do this:

```
my_file = '/directory1/directory2/the_file.txt'
xyz = PriceProcesseor(my_file)
xyz.the_works()
```

I get the error message:

```
NameError: global name 'csv' is not defined
```

What is being done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `import` statements outside the class definition.

```
import csv
import datetime

class PriceProcesseor(object):
#etc.
```

The class block creates a scope.  When you import things in that scope, they are only accessible in that scope.  The class scope is not directly accessible to methods of the class, so they can't see the imported modules.

Comment: You're right, this is definitely the proper solution.  One nitpick, you might say "the class scope is not *directly* accessible" since the methods *can access* the class scope (indirectly) via:  `PriceProcesseor.whatever` or `self.__class__.whatever`

Comment: Wow I'm dumb, thank you. So just to rephrase what you said, Ishould just put the import statements into the .py file where they are in now, except put them not into the class like I have them, but on top of the class.

Answer (score 1):

So the correct way to do with would be the following:

```
import csv
import datetime

class PriceProcesseor(object):


    def __init__(self, text_file_with_prices):
        self.text_file_with_prices = text_file_with_prices
        self.file_each_date_is_a_list_of_strings = self.__turn_file_into_list()

    def __turn_file_into_list(self):
        self.text_file_with_prices1 = open(self.text_file_with_prices, 'rU')
        self.text_file_with_prices2 = csv.reader(self.text_file_with_prices1)
        return self.text_file_with_prices2

    def file_as_list(self):
        '''Returns the file as a list of strings'''
        self.whole_file_as_list_of_lists = []
        for x in self.file_each_date_is_a_list_of_strings:
            self.whole_file_as_list_of_lists.append(x)
        return self.whole_file_as_list_of_lists

    # Make a method that can return any given line

    def return_line(self,line_number):
        self.line_number = line_number
        return self.file_as_list()[line_number]

    def the_works(self):
        self.the_works_list = []
        for date in self.file_as_list():
            self.mini_list = []
            for item in date:
                if '/' in item:
                    self.date = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%m/%d/%y'))
```

Next I save the file as ABC123.py. When I type import ABC123 everything will work perfectly.